# Running unit tests in Pydev

Tags: unit-testing, ironpython, pydev

I am trying to run unit tests in Pydev using IronPython.

When I try to run a test with Ctrl+F9 the following error message shows up in the Eclipse console window:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '_getframe'

I figured out that I have to invoke the IronPython interpreter with the '-X:Frames' argument.

Setting up the arguments in the 'Arguments' tab under 'Run->Run Configurations...' doesn't work. They seem to disappear everytime I run (Ctrl+F9) and choose another test.

Clicking 'Run->Run As->Iron Python unit-test' shows up more and more options to choose from.

Is Eclipse/Pydev creating new run configurations everytime I run a different set of tests? How can I permanently pass the '-X:Frames' argument, so my tests will run under IronPython?

(In Python the tests run without any problem.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shouldn't really be needed... I've just fixed the PyDev unittest runner so that it works properly (just pushed a new nightly build with that fix included -- if you're in Aptana Studio 3, a nightly is still not available, but you can patch your own version by applying the changes from the commit locally, as they're all changes in Python code: https://github.com/aptana/Pydev/commit/d5d262dbcd0c126ec0ec37e116ff79575c5dd6d8)